# Customize label for default _execute_action in Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

My Chrome extension executes a single function, which the user can bind to a keyboard shortcut by visiting chrome://extensions/shortcuts.

I want to customize the description of the action, which currently says "Activate the extension" by default.

I know I can [add my own custom command](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/commands/), but then I end up with two items (as shown below), one that says "Activate the extension" and one that says "My Custom Command". I just want one item that says "My Custom Command" instead of saying "Activate the extension".

Or equivalently, how can I remove the "Activate the extension" item?

[image]

To produce the screenshot above, I added this in manifest.json:

```json
  "commands": {
    "my-custom-command": {
      "description": "My Custom Command"
    }
  }
```

Comment: It can't be customized: [source](https://crsrc.org/chrome/browser/extensions/api/developer_private/extension_info_generator.cc;l=190-191;drc=8f3f6bf61bbc2d4783090c396c38aacba62c71e2).